# How to resolve a JSON-LD value?

Tags: semantic-web, json-ld

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "mkdocs": "https://mkdocs.iolanta.tech/",
    "table": "https://mkdocs.iolanta.tech/tables/",

    "description": "mkdocs:description",

    "table:rows": {
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "table:columns": {
      "@id": "table:columns",
      "@type": "@id",
      "@container": "@list"
    }
  },

  "$id": "table",
  "table:columns": [
    "description"
  ],
  "table:rows": [
    {
      "description": "foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

In JSON-LD playground, I am testing [a simple document](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/json-ld/raw-file/default/playground/index.html#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22mkdocs%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmkdocs.iolanta.tech%2F%22%2C%22table%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmkdocs.iolanta.tech%2Ftables%2F%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22mkdocs%3Adescription%22%2C%22table%3Arows%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22table%3Acolumns%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22table%3Acolumns%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40list%22%7D%7D%2C%22%24id%22%3A%22table%22%2C%22table%3Acolumns%22%3A%5B%22description%22%5D%2C%22table%3Arows%22%3A%5B%7B%22description%22%3A%22foo%22%7D%5D%7D) that has to describe a piece of tabular data.

I want to interpret the word `description` to resolve into `mkdocs:description`. The expanded form shows that this doesn't happen for every place where that word is used:

```json
[
  {
    "https://mkdocs.iolanta.tech/tables/columns": [
      {
        "@list": [
          {
            "@id": "https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/json-ld/raw-file/default/playground/description"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "https://mkdocs.iolanta.tech/tables/rows": [
      {
        "https://mkdocs.iolanta.tech/description": [
          {
            "@value": "foo"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In `table:rows` block, the term `description` is a key; in `table:columns`, it is a value. I assume that is the reason for it not being resolved.

Is there a way for me to construct a JSON-LD description in such a way that `description` in `table:columns` block is resolved into `mkdocs:description` and any other keyword (such as `some-random-column`) is resolved against the base URL of the document (which in this case happens to be the URL of the JSON-LD playground)?